# Plotting a set of (X, Y, Z) points as a nice closed object?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have a 3D object that is represented by a set of X, Y, Z points. If I use the command scatter3(X, Y, Z) I get the points but I would like this to be 'interpolated' so that I have a smooth 3D object. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Example of point cloud: [image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to triangulate between the points

```
TRI = delaunay( X, Y, Z );
trisurf( TRI, X, Y, Z );
```

Comment: When I run TRI = delaunay( X, Y, Z ) it says ??? Error using ==> cgprechecks at 14
OPTIONS should be a cell array of strings.

Comment: @sam what version of matlab are you using? try `>> doc delaunay` to see how to pass the arguments for the function.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using a newer version of matlab but it is not exactly what I want.. I don't want to interpolate between all points as it is doing but rather just fill in smaller gaps. This probably doesn't make much sense but my object is just a point cloud, I want to view it without having to look at a point cloud.

Comment: @Sam are you interested in viewing its convex hull?

Comment: @sam I'm not sure I follow your problem, can you post a picture of the point cloud, a picture of the corresponding `trisurf` and maybe an illustration of what you actually wish to have.

Comment: I'm basically trying to reconstruct an object using the shape from silhouette method. I will post some pics up.

Comment: This is the point cloud I have. http://i.imgur.com/N2ETLWN.png It's supposed to be a dinosaur. I want it to be smooth and solid. When I use the trisurf method it just becomes a big polygon like shape.